# Mark pie charts on top of geoshape in Altair/Vega

Tags: altair, vega

I love the recent developments to the Altair library and I was wondering if there was any advice for marking pie charts at different "latitudes" or "longitudes" of a geoshape. I have attached an image below showing a small example of what I'd like the rendered graphic to look similar to.

My understanding from the Altair/Vega documentation is that one can only mark [symbols](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/symbol/) onto the marked geoshape.   Would the best way forward be to create a new SVG for each of the slices of the pie chart and rotate them accordingly at each of the latitude/longitude coordinates?  Any advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated! Alternatively, if there is another visualization library that is better suited for this task I would be happy to hear about it.[image: Visualization of Pie Charts on top of geoshape]

Comment: I think you would have to create your own symbols for that. Something like this https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/isotype.html. Another way would be to save the pie charts and then use the image mark on top of the geo shape like herehttps://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/marks.html?highlight=image#user-guide-image-mark